# Length of the UDP packets are written incorrectly

Tags: java, udp, multicast, fileoutputstream, bytebuffer

I wrote small program that is receives UDP packets and persists their data into a file.

```
        MulticastSocket socket = getMulticastSocket(interfaceAddress, multicastAddress, port);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            while(true) {
                byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                int length = packet.getLength();
                ByteBuffer lengthBB = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthBytes);
                lengthBB.putInt(length);
                fos.write(lengthBB.array());
                fos.flush();
                fos.write(data, 0, length);
                fos.flush();
            }
        }
```

after that I am trying to read it use following code

```
final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
byte[] length = new byte[4];
while (inputStream.read(length) != -1){
    int receivedLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(length).getInt();
    byte[] body = new byte[receivedLength];
    inputStream.read(body);
    // doing something with body
    length = new byte[4];
}
```

it works in general but in the middle of file I have got negative value in  receivedLength variable (-2147483648 and [-128, 0, 0, 0] in byte representation).

BUFFER_SIZE = 10240 but I do not think that package was greater than this value.

Question: why did it happen?

p.s. I do not have an access to machine where the file was written and I cannot look at the network stream. I have only the file.

Comment: You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. You should be using `DataInputStream.readFully()`, which does. And `DataInpitStream.readInt()`.

Comment: @EJP I tried to use DataInputStream but I get the same result. I think there is some issue in my writter. Unfortunately I don't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a UDP message is 64K.  You said that you don't think the packet was bigger than 10240 but it could be.  Try increasing your buffer to 64 * 1024 and see if that changes the results.

Comment: Could you explain that why I have got the negative value? I tried to test it and send packets bigger than the buffer but the getLength method returned me size of my buffer(10240)

Comment: I would have to experiment to see how this would behave if you tried to fit a number too large into a buffer slightly too small.  But if your buffer were slightly too small and you ended up with a 1 in the leftmost bit, it would display as a negative number.